# I want to make a prolog program to do sum of non-duplicate numbers

Tags: arrays, prolog

This is my sum program I want edit it to remove the  duplicate ...

```
sum([], N):-N=0,!.
    sum([H|T], N):- sum(T, X),
     N is X + H.
```

Input [4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1]. Output 13 (i.e. 4+5+3+1)

Comment: This question needs some clarification. What should be the input and output of `sum`?

Comment: Also, it seems to be almost identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009100/sum-unique-number-in-a-list-in-prolog).

Comment: I answered the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084998/how-to-remove-the-repeated-members-in-a-simple-list-prolog/59124274#59124274

Comment: its the same question.Hope that helps you.