# How to remove the repeated members in a simple list [ prolog ]

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

EDIT :
How can I remove the repeated members in a simple list

for example :

[a,b,b,b,c,c,e] in this list the are 2 c and 3 b
and I want to remove all members that's repeated 
the result should be like this
[a,e]

keep in mind I'm  just learning the basic just for an assignment and I'm using the swish online compiler

Comment: HI, could you please share your solution (or solution idea)? The site is not made to directly produce a solution, but instead help you to solve  doubts, debug, refine and implement from pseudocode.

Comment: Sort the list, for instance with msort/2 in swipl and then scan the list and keep a counter of the occurrences of the current character and the most occurrences.

Comment: I've edited the problem .. please check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited my previous code.
My previous code gives the output in reverse order.

I used cut here so that it wouldn't backtrack all the possibilities of takeout function.
Hope this helps you.

I think this is the solution you were looking for.

```
takeout(X,[X|R],R).
takeout(X,[F|Fs],[F|S]):- takeout(X,Fs,S).
/* takeout function is used to delete
given element from the list.*/

ap([],L,L).
ap(L,[],L).
ap([H|T],L,[H|Z]):- ap(T,L,Z).
/* ap function is used to append
elements to a list. */


unique([X],_,[X]).
unique([H|T],X,Z):-  ( member(H,T) ; member(H,X) ) , ap([H],X,Xs) , takeout(H,[H|T],B) ,!, unique(B,Xs,Z).
unique([H|T],X,[H|Z]):- \+member(H,T) , \+member(H,X) , takeout(H,[H|T],Ts) ,!, unique(Ts,X,Z).
```

**output**

```
?- unique([1,2,2,3,3,4],[],M).

M= [1,4]
false
```

**For adding the elements of the list**

```
sum([H,H1|T],Z):- Z1 is H+H1 , sum([Z1|T],Z).
sum([X],X).

?- sum([1,2,3],Z).
   Z=6
   false
```

Comment: what if I want to get the sum of the result ? what I have to change

Comment: You need to keep on adding elements in the head until only one value is left in tail.

Comment: All you have do is call unique and pass the list that is the output of unique to sum.

Comment: query can be written as unique([1,2,2,3,3,4],[],M) , sum(M,Z). answers is M=[1,4] Z=5

Answer (score 1):

Even I started learning prolog recently. so I implemented the above problem using basic functions.
Coming to the logic I used.

Suppose if the list is [1,2,2,3,3,4], create List named Duplicate(initially empty).

1. we will check if the Head element is present in the tail of the list or Duplicate List.

2. If present in either of Lists then add the Head element to List  Duplicate, now takeout the Head element.

3. Else if not present in tail and Duplicate, takeout the Head element and add it to List Answer.

4. Repeat the above steps until the original list becomes empty.

```
takeout(X,[X|R],R).
takeout(X,[F|Fs],[F|S]):- takeout(X,Fs,S).
/* takeout function is used to delete
given element from the list.*/

ap([],L,L).
ap(L,[],L).
ap([H|T],L,[H|Z]):- ap(T,L,Z).
/* ap function is used to append
elements to a list. */


unique([],_,Z):- write(Z),!.
unique([H|T],X,Z):-  ( member(H,T) ; member(H,X) ) , ap([H],X,Xs) , takeout(H,[H|T],B) , unique(B,Xs,Z).
unique([H|T],X,Z):- \+member(H,T) , \+member(H,X) , ap([H],Z,Zs) , takeout(H,[H|T],Ts) , unique(Ts,X,Zs).
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]